# Strange behavior when using toDF() function to transfrom RDD to Dataframe in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I am new in Spark. And when I use toDF() function to convert RDD to dataframe, it seems to compute all the transformation function like map() I've written before. I wonder if toDF() in PySpark is a transformation or an action.

I create a simple RDD and use a simple function to output its value, just for test, And use toDF() after map(). The result seems to run the function in map partially. And when I show the result of dataframe, toDF() act like transformation and output the result again.

```
>>> a = sc.parallelize([(1,),(2,),(3,)])
>>> def f(x):
...     print(x[0])
...     return (x[0] + 1, )
...
>>> b = a.map(f).toDF(["id"])
2
1
>>> b = a.map(f).toDF(["id"]).show()
2
1
1
2
3
+---+
| id|
+---+
|  2|
|  3|
|  4|
+---+
```

Could someone tell me why toDF() function in PySpark act both like action and transformation? Thanks a lot.

PS: In Scala, toDF act like transformation in my case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not strange. Since you didn't provide the schema, Spark has to infer it based on the data. If the `RDD` is an input, it will call [`SparkSession._createFromRDD`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/d367bdcf521f564d2d7066257200be26b27ea926/python/pyspark/sql/session.py#L414) and subsequently [`SparkSession._inferSchema`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/3c0e9ce944d98859939bbcbf21c610f4b9b224dd/python/pyspark/sql/session.py#L382), which, if `samplingRatio` is missing, [will evaluate up to 100 row](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/3c0e9ce944d98859939bbcbf21c610f4b9b224dd/python/pyspark/sql/session.py#L390-L407):

```
first = rdd.first()
if not first:
    raise ValueError("The first row in RDD is empty, "
                     "can not infer schema")
if type(first) is dict:
    warnings.warn("Using RDD of dict to inferSchema is deprecated. "
                  "Use pyspark.sql.Row instead")


if samplingRatio is None:
    schema = _infer_schema(first, names=names)
    if _has_nulltype(schema):
        for row in rdd.take(100)[1:]:
            schema = _merge_type(schema, _infer_schema(row, names=names))
            if not _has_nulltype(schema):
                break
        else:
            raise ValueError("Some of types cannot be determined by the "
                             "first 100 rows, please try again with sampling")
```

Now the only puzzle left if why it doesn't evaluate exactly one record. After-all in  your case `first` is not empty and doesn't contain `None`.

That's because `first` is implemented through `take` and doesn't guarantee that the exact number of items will evaluated. If the first partition doesn't yield the required number of items, it will iteratively increase number of partitions to scan. Please check [the implementation](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/08c76b5d39127ae207d9d1fff99c2551e6ce2581/python/pyspark/rdd.py#L1306-L1365) for details.

If you want to avoid this you should use `createDataFrame` and provide schema either as DDL string:

```
spark.createDataFrame(a.map(f), "val: integer")
```

or equivalent `StructType`.

You won't find any similar behavior in Scala counterpart, because it doesn't use schema inference in `toDF`. It either retrieves corresponding schema from the `Encoder` (which is fetched using Scala reflection), or doesn't allow conversion at all. The closest similar behavior is inference on input source like CSV [or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38924623/10465355):

```scala
spark.read.json(Seq("""{"foo": "bar"}""").toDS.map(x => { println(x); x }))
```

Comment: Thank you so so much. This answer is exactly what I need.