# why spark read csv generate three jobs

Tags: apache-spark

I tried simple example on spark 2.1cloudra2:

```
val flightData2015 = spark
  .read
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .option("header", "true")
  .csv("/2015-summary.csv")
```

but when I check spark shell UI,I found it generate three jobs:
[image]

I think every action should related to a job,am I right? I do some experiment found out every option can generate a job. Does option act like action? please help understand this situation.

Comment: [Why does SparkSession execute twice for one action?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38924623/10465355)

Answer (score -2):

@yuxh,its because of the `defaultMinPartitions` which have been set to 3.It reflects  Parallelism when a spark job is executed.You can change it in `yarn-site.xml` globally or dynamically specific to a job by issuing `sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "your value”)`

Comment: I don't think so,I can reduce job by deleting option function and job has nothing to do with  Parallelism

Comment: What was the reason for downvote? Did you try executing the settings and started the spark job?