# WIthout persisting or caching does Spark read the data from disk on every action?

Tags: apache-spark

For simplicty's sake and in pseudocode, if I do `myDF = spark.read.option('inferSchema', True).json(someFiles)` and then I do `myDF.count()` does spark read the data from disk twice?

Answer (score 0):

- If DAG contains only narrow transformations Spark will read data on each action.
- In fact in your case it will read data two times although there is only one action - [Why does SparkSession execute twice for one action?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38924623)
- If DAG contains wide transformations Spark can reuse shuffle files in some cases - [What does "Stage Skipped" mean in Apache Spark web UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34580662) - that however won't happen here.