# spark.read.json on an RDD - function runs twice when cached and counted

Tags: json, apache-spark

It seems that using `spark.read.json` within a function causes that function to run twice - once when it is cached, and then again when the result is counted.

Example code:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

def foo(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
  val barRdd = df.rdd.map { row =>
    println("Hello World!\n")
    row.getAs[String](0)
  }
  spark.read.json(barRdd).cache
}

val df = sc.parallelize(
    Seq("[{'col1': 'hello', 'col2': 'world'}, {'col1': 'foo', 'col2': 'bar'}]")
).toDF("data")
```

If I run the above in a spark-shell and then run:

```scala
val df2 = foo(df)
df2.count
```

I would expect to see `'Hello World'` printed only once (because the `DataFrame` is only fully instantiated when the count happens). However, in fact, `'Hello World'` appears twice, once when the function is initially run and once when the count happens.

If I remove `spark.read.json` and replace the line with with `barRdd.toDF("col1").cache`, then `'Hello World'` is printed once, as I would expect.

This is causing problems for us when calling an external API with a limited request quota. Why is this happening and what can we do to get around it?

I am on spark 2.4.3 and running this in a spark-shell.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does SparkSession execute twice for one action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38924623/why-does-sparksession-execute-twice-for-one-action)

Comment: @user10938362 Thanks, this is the answer I needed! Couldn't find this in the search earlier.